# COUNTIFS for Last 10 Matching Entries

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WHSVcoh-mtfK-8wzg5IXZVWtfn0r4ZnMmXs7SQBEf10/edit?usp=sharing)

Tab `Ladder` - `Col J` has a `COUNTIFS` formula that calculates % of matching criteria within the last 24hrs.  I would like to limit the calculation to the last 10 matching entries within the 24hr window.

I have a stub formula in `J35` outlining how I would like it structured.  I have done a lot of searching, and while I have found a few examples of "Last x rows" - I haven't been able to translate those concepts to my specific needs.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of your:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$18:$A, ">"&Dates!$C$4+TIME(Dates!$C$3,0,0)-1,
          $D$18:$D, $D35,
          $H$18:$H, $H35,
          $Y$18:$Y, "")
```

use:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER(ROW($A$18:$A), 
 $A$18:$A>Dates!$C$4+TIME(Dates!$C$3,0,0)-1,
 $D$18:$D=$D35,
 $H$18:$H=$H35,
 $Y$18:$Y=""), "limit 10")))
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for your help.  I thought it was you!  <3

Answer (score 0):

I have also discovered that the following nested `QUERY` would work - though I would have to restructure the sheet a little bit so that the formula was outside of the bounds of the `QUERY` so not to trigger a circular dependency.

`=QUERY(QUERY($A$18:$Y, "Select T Where H = '"&$H35&"' and D = '"&$D35&"' and E = '"&$E35&"' Order by C desc limit 10", 0), "select avg(Col1) label avg(Col1)''", 0)`

Comment: I should add that the `COUNTIFS` was just a portion of a longer formula.  I determined that if I could get the answer to that small segment of the formula I could extrapolate it out.  The above formula goes a further step in my formula and is much more concise.  I appreciate player0's help as always - but I'll probably run with this formula.